# Load a csv file with specific columns using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a table structure like this:

```
id
assigned_by
assigned_to_user_id
vendor_id
receiver_no
purchase_order_no
destination
po_status
invoice_no
invoice_amount
delivery_date
datetime_done
latest_jda_sync_date
latest_mobile_sync_date
created_at
updated_at
deleted_at
```

And the content of my csv file is like this:

```
vendor_id receiver_no purchase_order_no destination po_status
30105   20110   10151   9005    3
50015   20114   10155   9005    3
```

And right now I'm able to load the csv file and insert them in my database. I have this script below.

```
$columns = "(@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, vendor_id, receiver_no, purchase_order_no, destination, po_status, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy)";
$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
      LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)." ". $columns);
```

The only problem I'm having is inserting the data to the correct column. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> When processing an input line, [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) splits it into fields and uses the values according to the column/variable list and the `SET` clause, if they are present.

In other words, the column list should describe *the database columns* (or user variables) to which each *the input fields* should be assigned (rather than describing in which input field each database column can be found).  This is, of course, obvious when one realises that the input file need not contain field names and thus it would be impossible to adopt the latter approach in all circumstances.

Therefore, you want:

```
$columns = '(vendor_id, receiver_no, purchase_order_no, destination, po_status)';
```

You will also need to add `IGNORE 1 LINES` to the command in order to skip the first line (with field names):

```
$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
      LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)."
      IGNORE 1 LINES ". $columns);
```

Comment: hi eggyal, it works!. I have another question. Can you add in your script the IGNORE DUPLICATE part, from what I understand these remove the duplicate data before it gets inserted in my db. Because I will be pulling another csv file with additional contents. Sorry

Comment: @user2720708: If you have a suitable uniqueness constraint defined in your table, then you merely need add either `IGNORE` (to keep the existing data) or `REPLACE` (to delete the record and replace with the new data) after the file name.  It's all detailed in the manual.  Please post a separate question describing what problems you are having, if any.

Comment: hi, i've posted my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580157/how-to-avoid-duplicate-data-when-using-load-data-infile

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which columns you want to use (it seems you have them mucked about in order of how your statement executes):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3, ...)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

See the [manual for more details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).